# How to Start without Debugging (CTRL+F5) with just one finger instead of using two in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

The Start Without Debugging option is great for quick checks. The ease of the F5 button loads it with the debugger but it takes a lot of time everytime it runs.

Is it possible to switch F5 and CTRL+F5 around, so by pressing only F5 it Starts Without Debugging instead of Start Debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Tools -> Options
- Environment -> Keyboard
- Filter list with 'Debug.Start'
- Choose Remove 'Shortcuts for selected commands:' for both Debug.StartWithoutDebugging and Debug.Start
- Assign both with reversed commands.

Screenshot for final step of assiging F5 to Debug.StartWithoutDebugging:
[image]

The reverted keyboard shortcuts are then also shown in the menu:

[image]

Comment: Please don't forget to [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), it will also help other people who want the same feature. Thanks for sharing your insights.

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration from Debug to Release